# Creating a Class instance that returns a value

Tags: python

I have this

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,arg_1,arg_2):
         self.arg_1 = arg_1
         self.arg_2 = arg_2
    def method(self):
        <do_some_stuff with self.arg_1 and self.arg_2>
        return result
```

(Changed the return line. We do some computations with arg_1 and arg_2, and then return some value. A previous version of this line seemed to be causing some confusion)

Right now, the way I'm using this is

```
instance = MyClass(arg_1)
instance_method = instance.method()
```

The way I would like it to work is just by `instance_method = MyClass(arg_1)`.

I've read that `__new__` magic method is capable of returning values instead of class instances. However, I'm not sure how to do it, or even if it's the best way. The `__init__` method, which doesn't return anything, is only called after the `__new__` method,and the `__new__` would need attributes

I've also thought of something like a class decorator, but class decorators decorate class methods, not class initialisations...

P.S.: the more I think about it, the more I believe what I should be using is simply a function.

P.S.2: Thank you all for the comments and replies. I decided to simply use a function. ;)

Comment: Sounds like you want a function, not a class in the first place…?!

Comment: You could overload `__call__`, which would make you class callable like a function: `c = MyClass(arg_1); c()`

Comment: "P.S.: the more I think about it, the more I believe what I should be using is simply a function." - so write a function?

Comment: I don't think that is your code as it would generate a TypeError due to missing a parameter in the class constructor

Comment: The __ init __ of your class receives 2 arguments (arg1, arg2), so when you create it, you should pass 2 arguments ```instance_method = MyClass(arg_1, arg_2)```.
Also, when you call the ```some_function``` (which I don't think it's necessary, you could do it in the ```method``` itself), you have to use ```self.arg_1```, and not just ```arg_1```.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and replies. I decided to simply use a function.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to save the created instance you can just do

```py
x = MyClass(arg_1).method()
```

However, if you don't need to use the instance anywhere afterwards, then you probably don't have a reason to create the class in the first place. In that case, you would be better of using a function.

Maybe what you are looking for is a [static method](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/staticmethod).